# Grub rescue error after deleting Ubuntu partition

Tags: grub, boot-partition

I was using Windows 7 and Ubuntu as dual boot,then I decided to remove Ubuntu.I deleted Ubuntu partition from my Windows-> Disk Management and extended the unused volumes with other windows partitions.

After that when I restarted, I found my Windows is not booting and I'm getting a grub rescue prompt.When I put my bootable windows CD or Ubuntu CD it's not getting detected either.I manually selected the device to boot from as CD drive, still my bootable CD's are not loading and I get the grub rescue prompt.

I have tried to play around with grub rescue commands but its not working either.It gives unknown filesystem as response most of the time.

Comment: In short, boot up with Windows boot disk, run command line,  type the command `bootrec.exe /fixmbr`. See more:: https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on

Comment: The boot disk is not getting detected.Thats the problem.

Comment: yea i tried that too...

Comment: problem is not with the boot order..its set to cd/dvd only... in addition i tried manually specifying to boot from cd/dvd .Still its not working.

Comment: Is your windows boot is alright and try if it works in any other machine?

Comment: Tried an old XP CD luckily it got booted..but since I had no intention to install XP I didn't install it.After that when I tried with Windows 7 CD it was booting and I repaired the boot using fixmbr.